# C# How to build an expression tree for Exists() on a List<T>

Tags: c#, tree, expression-trees

```
List<string> strlist = new List<string> { "one","two", "three" };
string somevalue = "two";

var result = strlist.Exists(e2 => e2 == somevalue);
```

How to convert the last statement Exists() to an expression tree?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you mean by *"convert to an expression tree"*? What is the output you're looking for?

Comment: Also, you can simplify the code a little by using the `Contains` method since you're not doing any custom comparison, i.e. `var result = strlist.Contains(somevalue);`

Comment: to build an expression tree, so a list can be checked for the presence of a matching element.

Comment: @vicport As per Rufus' answer, the expression here is not complex enough that it needs to be solved with an expression tree. Just use the `.Contains()` method and you should be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create an expression tree from a lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) and then compile it into a function that can then be invoked with the `strlist` and `somevalue` arguments like this:

```
var strlist = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
var somevalue = "two";

Expression<Func<List<string>, string, bool>> expression = (list, value) => 
    list.Exists(item => item == value);

Func<List<string>, string, bool> exists = expression.Compile();

bool result = exists(strlist, somevalue);
```

Or you could do it all in one line, but it's a little hard to read:

```
var exists = ((Expression<Func<List<string>, string, bool>>)
    ((list, value) => list.Exists(item => item == value))).Compile();
```

But in the end, isn't it simpler to just do:

```
bool result = strlist.Contains(somevalue);
```